# Textile error: using url's results in compilation error

Tags: php, regex, textile

When using this simple textile markup the textile class seems to give a compilation error. It appears to happen with links:

```
"linktext":http://www.nu.nl
["linktext":http://www.nu.nl]
```

Compilation error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 5 in /var/www/vhosts/sturb.nl/subdomains/bu/httpdocs/lib/textile.php on line 1355
```

All the other markup show like normal.

BTW: I'm using [netcarver's](https://github.com/netcarver/textile) textile php class.

Edit:
This is the function in which the error gets triggered.
Line 1355 is the `$ok = preg_match( $r, $uri, $m );`

```
function parseURI( $uri, &$m )
{
    $r = "@^((?<scheme>[^:/?#]+):)?(//(?<authority>[^/?#]*))?(?<path>[^?#]*)(\?(?<query>[^#]*))?(#(?<fragment>.*))?@";
    #       12                     3  4                      5              6  7                8 9
    #
    #   scheme    = $2
    #   authority = $4
    #   path      = $5
    #   query     = $7
    #   fragment  = $9

    $ok = preg_match( $r, $uri, $m );
    return $ok;
}
```

Comment: I added the preg_match function which triggers the error

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the '#' sign in your regex (the one not in a character class). They have to be escaped normally.

**Update**

Aparently, in php, the # is treated as a literal unless the //x modifier is specified. Then it would have to be escaped if used as a literal.

The error you are getting means that the version of PHP being used does not support 'named capture buffers'. I'm not sure what version of php implements that.

I looked at the textfile php class you named, and that function is indeed there. I don't know if they supply php for you or you are using your own. I'm not a php expert.

The version of PHP used on ideone.com to run my test case is *5.2.11* which supports named capture buffers.

One way to tell is that you can convert the named constructs from `(?<name> -- )` to `( -- )`. That should run, or at least get you past that sub-expression.

Here is a test case with/without named capture buffers http://ideone.com/dm4Q8
Try to find out what version is being used, maybe its got a built in 'version()' function.

Here is an expanded/contracted regex to test with.

```
'~
^(
   ([^:/?#]+)
   :
 )?
 (
   //
   ([^/?#]*)
 )?
 ([^?#]*)
 (
   \?
   ([^#]*)
 )?
 (
   \#
   (.*)
 )?
 ~x';

'~^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?~'
```

Comment: It appears to be an other problem;  the expanded regex doesn't work... It says: `unrecognized character after (?< at offset 73 in`

Comment: @stUrb - I updated my answer to include a regex without named capture buffers. If it works, you should update the version of PHP. By and large though `(?` .. `)` is a regex escape sequence grouping. The next char(s) past `?` determine what it is. So "(?`<n`ame> )" is not recognized, meaning no support for named capture buffers.